# C++ application crashesbecause of unknown reason?

Tags: c++, qt

I don't know why but my QT application is crashing every time at the `//Error` (in last function of .cpp file) comment. Do you guys know why? I unfortunately have no debugger here :/

ServerSys.cpp

```
#include "ServerSys.hpp"
#include "ui_ServerSys.h"
#include "ServerNet.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <QDesktopWidget>

Ui::ServerSys *serverSys;

ServerSys::ServerSys(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::ServerSys)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    serverSys = ui;
    this->setFixedSize(QSize(811, 521));
    this->setGeometry(QApplication::desktop()->screen()->rect().center().x() / 2, 500, 811, 521);
}

ServerSys::~ServerSys()
{
    delete ui;
}

void ServerSys::sendData()
{
    std::vector<long long> decTokens(8);
    std::vector<std::string> binTokens(8);
    std::vector<bool> binLabel;
    long long decLabel;

    getData(decTokens);
}

void ServerSys::getData(std::vector<long long> &decTokens)
{


    //Error
    decTokens[0] = stoll(serverSys->lineEdit_label_270->text().toStdString());


    decTokens[1] = stoll(serverSys->lineEdit_sdi_270->text().toStdString());
    decTokens[2] = stoll(serverSys->lineEdit_distance_270->text().toStdString());
    decTokens[3] = stoll(serverSys->lineEdit_lsb_270->text().toStdString());
    decTokens[4] = stoll(serverSys->lineEdit_msb_270->text().toStdString());
    decTokens[5] = 0;
    decTokens[6] = stoll(serverSys->lineEdit_ssm_270->text().toStdString());
    decTokens[7] = stoll(serverSys->lineEdit_parity_270->text().toStdString());
}
```

ServerSys.hpp

```
#ifndef SERVERUI_HPP
#define SERVERUI_HPP

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui
{
    class ServerSys;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class ServerSys : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ServerSys(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~ServerSys();
    void sendData();

private:
    Ui::ServerSys *ui;
    void getData(std::vector<long long>&);
};

#endif // SERVERUI_HPP
```

As I have tried to debug it manually with

```
std::string test = serverSys->lineEdit_label_270->text().toStdString();
std::cout << test << std::endl;
```

the application crashed not but `test` was nothing and there was no output. For all tests I certainly writed some numbers in the line-edit field like `123`.

Comment: What about `std::stoll(test)`?

Comment: Leads to a crash because `test` is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::stoll` throws an `std::invalid_argument` exception when the conversion isn't possible. That's likely the crash you are experiencing, especially if your other test revealed that the string was already empty.

`Ui::ServerSys *serverSys;` as a global variable is a really weird thing to do, if you already have `ui` as a member variable available in the same scope, but at least that *should* not cause any trouble as long as long as there is really only a single `ServerSys` instance *ever*.

As for what actually went wrong? Well, two likely options:

- `sendData()` was called on an instance of `ServerSys` which was already deleted. Given the code, you wouldn't notice otherwise except when attempting to read from also potentially free'd instance of widgets in your `Ui::ServerSys` instance.
- You have more line edits in the form that you intended, and you read from the wrong ones. Double check in the designer if the widgets actually have the name you though they did.

Either way, `QString` has a useful method [`toLongLong()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLongLong) which doesn't use exceptions, so you should really be using that one directly rather than a `try { std::stoll([...].toStdString()) } catch(...)` detour.

Comment: 1. I used `Ui::ServerSys *serverSys;` as global variable because I needed access to the ui components in multiple functions which I haden't taken in my class ServerSys. But now I have and I removed the global variable, thanks for the tip!

2. The function `toLongLong()` worked, thank you very much!